# Custom view not filling parent

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a custom view like this

```
public class ButtonBar extends HorizontalScrollView
{
  public View mButtonRows;

  public ButtonBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mButtonRows = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar, null);

    // button click handling code goes here

    addView(mButtonRows);
  }
}
```

which is included in my main xml like this

```
<com.example.ButtonBar
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/pagecontent" />
```

and inflates an xml file like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/ButtonsRow" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:text="button1"
  />
  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:text="button2"
  />
  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:text="button3"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

(It currently only has three buttons, but more are going to be needed in later versions, hence the HorizontalScrollView.)

Looking in hierarchyviewer, the custom view does seem to be screen wide, but the LinearLayout is only as wide as the buttons it contains (about 2/3 of the screen at the current button size), despite having the `fill_parent` width set; the buttons don't stretch.  If I set the LinearLayout's background to `@android:drawable/bottom_bar` (which is a png the width of the screen), the buttons properly resize; I realise I could do the same thing by creating my own images to match, but I'd much rather do it without if possible.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**ETA:** if I change HorizontalScollView to ScrollView, it works fine.  Do HSVs just not allow their children to "fill_parent"?

---

**ETA2:** Setting `android:fillViewport="true"` in the main xml fixed it!

Comment: So, basically, you see three buttons on a horizontal line each taking 1/3 of the screen width?

Comment: I should see that.  What I actually see is three buttons of default width (ie, as if I'd used `layout_width="wrap_content"`) taking up about 2/3 of the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting android:fillViewport="true" in the main xml fixed it!

Comment: It's a little stupid -- it's actually the top thing in the HorizontalScrollView reference, I just compeltely missed it until I was reading through ScrollView to find out why one worked and the other didn't. /o\

Answer (score 0):

If you change to this, for each of the buttons, does it work?

```
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't.  In Eclipse, if I look at the button bar xml in Graphical Layout view, both my version and yours stretch to fit the screen as expected, but when the button bar is pulled in to the other layout it doesn't.  I'm sure I must just be doing something stupid somewhere, but I don't know what.